# Automatically transfer data from iPhone Notes app to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iphone, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to write a Python program to extract daily info from the Notes app on my iPhone, and enter it directly to a Pandas dataframe.

For instance:

In the Notes app I enter the date, time, and my weight each day.

That information is then read into a Pandas dataframe directly from the Notes app

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible.

Comment: Probably possible. Depends if there is some kind of API for the Notes app.

Comment: Good suggestion. Looking for API now